# Return correct row from a particular set of rows within the range

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, match

I have below sample extract of movement of deals from the CRM. I use the formula: `=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$21=1)*($D$2:$D$21<$P$2)*$D$2:$D$21,))`, where `P2` is a date, to extract the last movement of deal "1" prior to the date in `P2` (currently set to 01/10/2020). I get 12/09/2020 which is correct.

From here, I will need to return its particular row number and I try to use the MATCH formula: `MATCH(MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$21=1)*($D$2:$D$21<$P$2)*$D$2:$D$21,)),$D$2:$D$21,0)`. However, since the lookup array (`$D$2:$D$21`) is only looking up the date and doesn't consider for which deal it belongs, it doesn't always return the correct row number.

I need the lookup array to be narrowed down to the rows that belong to the particular deal ID. I also need the MATCH formula to return the last occurrence of the date in case there are several of them that happens within the same day (see Co C_Deal 1). Is there a more accurate way to do this?

I really appreciate any assistance and already thank you in advance for your help. Thanks thanks!

| Deal ID | Co Name | Deal | Date | Stage History |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Co A | Co A_Deal 1 | 02/02/2020 | Lead Qual |
| 1 | Co A | Co A_Deal 1 | 23/06/2020 | Demo |
| 1 | Co A | Co A_Deal 1 | 12/09/2020 | Proposal |
| 1 | Co A | Co A_Deal 1 | 01/10/2020 | Contracts |
| 1 | Co A | Co A_Deal 1 | 31/12/2020 | Won |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 16/01/2020 | Lead Qual |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 14/03/2020 | Proposal |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 15/03/2020 | Demo |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 30/07/2020 | Proposal |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 09/10/2020 | Contract |
| 2 | Co B | Co B_Deal 1 | 06/11/2020 | Won |
| 3 | Co C | Co C_Deal 1 | 16/09/2020 | Demo |
| 3 | Co C | Co C_Deal 1 | 16/09/2020 | Lead Qual |
| 3 | Co C | Co C_Deal 1 | 10/10/2020 | Proposal |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 03/04/2020 | Lead Qual |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 06/05/2020 | Proposal |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 13/05/2020 | Demo |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 12/09/2020 | Proposal |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 15/10/2020 | Contracts |
| 4 | Co D | Co D_Deal 1 | 28/11/2020 | Won |

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDEX(($D$2:$D$21<$H$2)*($A$2:$A$21)),$H$1,0)),ROW($D$2:$D$21),""))
```

Enter it as array formula. *$H$1* is cell with dealer ID.
Formula performs search for every occurrence that satisfies date and dealer ID condition and return maximal row number.